# Modifying the leading character in a formatted number in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting, number-formatting

I know that in Python 3.6+ we can use f-strings to format numbers with a width and precision:

```py
f"{value:{width}.{precision}}"
```

So I did the following:

```py
>>> print(f"My number: {31072021:015.1f}")
My number: 00000031072021.0
```

Now if I try the same code without a `0` before the `15` in the `{width}` specifier, then I get the following

```py
>>> print(f"My number: {31072021:15.1f}")
My number:       31072021.0
```

Now, is it possible to specify my own padding character instead of the default space   or zero `0` characters?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Since the answer is more general and contains format string which is more widely compatible wouldn't it be wise to change it to `python` instead of `python 3.9.6`

Comment: @Jo_L Thanks for the suggestion, I have modified the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to add a padding character of your liking in python, but not with the format string alone. We would have to use `rjust()` for that.

```py
>>> s = f"{31072021:.1f}".rjust(15, 'a')
'aaaaa31072021.0'

>>> # same as: s="{:.1f}".format(31072021).rjust(15, "a")

>>> print("My number:", s)
My number: aaaaa31072021.0
```

In your answer, the zero `0` padding appears because prepended zeros do not change the value of a number, so you will have the same value regardless of whether it is a space   or a zero `0`.